# Wix 3.5 desktop shortcut

Tags: wix, wix3.5

In my application, a shortcut to desktop is provided. After it's installed, when mouse points to shortcut, it shows location details (installation path).

What should do in order to hide this information in wix?

My code is:

```
<Component>
   <File Id ="Scan" Name="Scan.exe" Source="Scan.exe">
      <Shortcut Id ="Shortcut" Name="Scanner" Directory="DesktopFolder" Advertise="no" />      
   </File>
   <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Scanner\Company\Device" Name="Scan" Type="integer" Value="0" KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, the `Description` attribute defines what is displayed in the shortcut's tooltip.  It seems the installation path is the default value. So, I think you should add `Description` attribute to the `Shortcut` element in order to overwrite the text.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I have tried with Description attribute also.After adding it,tooltip shows both Name attribute and its Description attribute.Is there any way to show only one description either Name or Description?No location details.Pls help

Comment: @user970770 No, there's no such option, it's the way Shell is implemented in Windows. If the shortcut name is truncated on the desktop or in a folder view, it is displayed in tooltip (so that user can see the full name of the file); if the shortcut has Description, then it's displayed (with the full file name if necessary); if description is empty, then Location attribute of the shortcut is shown. You can try using advertised shortcuts, like in MS Office or Adobe Reader.